# Case-insensitive string.Contains for both IEnumerable and IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm writing a method that converts a custom language query into an `Expression` tree so that it can be used with `Where` extension methods on arbitrary collections. These collections can be `IEnumerable<T>` from memory lists, or `IQueryable<T>` for database queries.

My filter logic involves a lot of string contains checks to check whether the searched string occurs in some property of each object instance. I'm now using the standard call to `string.Contains` for that, which should translate to SQL `LIKE '%...%'` for SQL Server (and probably others as well) which should be case-insensitive in most database systems by default. But the .NET implementation of that method does something else: It is case-sensitive and will return other (less) objects from the collection because it's a more restrictive comparison.

I've spent the last couple hours finding and reading about this topic. `ToLower` and `ToUpper` won't work "properly" in [Turkey](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html). Is `ToLowerInvariant` supported for SQL generation? `IndexOf` sounds like a better alternative. `string.Contains` calls `string.IndexOf` internally. `IndexOf` has another overload that accepts a `StringComparison` value. But will that be supported for SQL generation? How would it translate if I specified `Ordinal` instead of `OrdinalIgnoreCase`?

This is all very frustrating. Databases are different from memory objects in .NET. But after all, Entity Framework merges both worlds and brings database queries directly into C#. It will cause all sorts of bugs if the semantics of common operations change depending on how they're executed at runtime.

Comment: This has not been my experience when working with EF.  Are you using MS SQL Server?  What is the collation of the table you are querying?

Comment: Any. My code is supposed to work with any database. It's kind of a library that developers may use in their applications, with whatever database they have. Or the user decides to use. Or with in-memory collections. The behaviour of my function should be the same in any case. In fact I wouldn't change the collation of an entire database (or table or column) just to have a single query work as expected. There may be other queries that require other collations which would be conflicting requirements. Non-default collations can't be the solution.

Comment: Welcome to the world of leaky abstractions. You absolutely don't want to feed a solution speckled with `ToLower`-like calls to an EF query if you know that the database collation is case-insensitive. It disables indexes and hampers query plan generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no generally accepted general solution to the problem. You have to be aware of what you are doing and where you are doing it unfortunately.

The core reason why is that SQL Server is not consistent with how it handles these kinds of queries. It is consistent with a consistent configuration, but that configuration isn't known for certain in the .NET environment.

There is no general way to know how `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%foo'` without actually running that query.

The best solution is to avoid any attempts to run queries like that locally, simply always call the database.

Comment: So I need to provide two different implementations of the `Contains` check for having the expression translated to SQL and for running it locally in applications that don't even have a database. And in situations where it's unclear whether an expression is still on the database side or already executed locally, the developer must decide which of the options to use.

Comment: @LonelyPixel: Since the identically written statements have different implementations, you either need to choose single statement, multiple implementations as LINQ to SQL did or different statements (for the same statement) as you are describing here.